# Cannot integrate Paytm iOS SDK V2.1

Tags: ios, sdk, paytm

I tried integrating Paytm iOS SDK 2.1. 
 Always give me the error -
`ld: library not found for -lPaymentsSDK`

I added the `libPaymentsSDK.a` to my frameworks and all the 5 files under include folder to my project. Is there any other step? 
The documentation of adding the SDK is not there at all. Only steps for integrating are there. If anyone is using the SDK please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the Paytm SDK uses Apple's reachability and it was interfering with the Reachability I was using. So I changed the name of the class of the Reachability(Non Apple one) I was using.